# What is new in SharePoint 2013 ?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, 2013

The SharePoint 2013 is now released. What is New in SharePoint 2013 ?
What are they added in SharePoint 2013 then SharePoint 2010 ?
What are the new features ?

Comment: An important note: the released version is only a preview version. This is an early release for testing and learning. I expect to see a RTM version late this year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything you need to know can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/fp142374.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Vesa "vesku" Juvonen has a nice post with [SharePoint 2013 IT Pro and Developer training materials released](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2012/07/17/sharepoint-2013-it-pro-and-developer-training-materials-released.aspx).

These give you a nice overview what is new in SharePoint 2013 for the IT Pro and the developer.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a good podcast on Dot net Rocks With Sahil Malik
http://s3.amazonaws.com/dnr/dotnetrocks_0794_sahil_malik.mp3

Answer (score 0):

**These are the possible improvements:**

User Experience Improvements

User Interface o Minimal Download Strategy o Site Navigation o Sharing  Social Enhancements o User Profiles o My Sites o Taxonomy o Microblogs o Newsfeed  Document Management Enhancements o Office Integration Differences o Office Web Apps  Licensing Information

Visual Studio

Visual Studio Tooling Enhancements

Apps for SharePoint 

Introduction to NAPA  Visual Studio App Project  Hosting Options o SharePoint Hosted o Provider Hosted o Azure Auto-hosted  App Security

API Enhancements

Server OM o Profile/social o Taxonomy o Search APIs  Client OM improvements  REST API additions and changes

UI Branding Enhancements 

Design Manager o Improvements in Master Page, Page Layout design o Design Packaging  Client Side Rendering

Search

Configuration Management Changes

Search Service Application o Site Collection o Site  Query Rules  Query Result Display Templates  API Changes  Client Side API  Server Query API  Content By Search Web Part

Web Content Management
  
Content Creation Changes  Managed Navigation and category pages  Image Renditions, image processing improvements  Cross-Site Publishing and publishing content across site collections  Variation Changes  Channels and device-specific targeting  Analytics

Workflow 

Architecture  o .NET 4.0 o Workflow Manager and Windows Azure Host  Out of the box Workflows  New Workflow Activities  Developing Custom Visual Studio Workflows  Developing Custom Activities