# What features have been lost in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013

There's been a lot of discussion around the new features in SharePoint 2013 ( [What is new in SharePoint 2013 ?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44875/what-is-new-in-sharepoint-2013) ), but I'm curious as to what's no longer offered/supported in 2013.

Does anyone have a comprehensive list?

Currently I'm only aware of the following two:

- Preview mode has been removed from Designer
- Sandbox solutions are now 'deprecated'

Comment: Please remember to make this kind of open ended questions Commnity Wiki!

Comment: @AndersRask: I've attempted to keep it non-CW by asking for a definitive list, and then attempting to provide such a list myself (please see below). Once the time limit has passed, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: There is no one simple answer to these kinds of questions. Hence they are already borderline on types of Q accepted in the forum. Collecting answers into one does not make it less wiki-like, in contrast you will have double answers, which all would have (and already have until made CW) received reputation. I would suggest cleaning up answers so that there are no doubles and closing Q after the time period is up.

Comment: @AndersRask Well, I see your point. However, the consolidated answer was already CW so there was no duplicate reputation.

Comment: Its not the point :) The point is this type of open ended answers really doesn't fit our Q/A concept very well and hence usually are not allowed. If they seem to add value we allow them but always make them CW. Duplicate answers though is not a good idea as it will only bring even more noise to answers. The reason they are made CW is to avoid people "horing for reputation". Read more on CW discusion [here](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67/enforcing-community-wiki-content) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Visual upgrade feature in SharePoint Server 2010 have been
   deprecated in SharePoint 2013.
2. Web Analytics are not available in SharePoint 2013. Analytics processing for
   SharePoint 2013 is now a component of the Search service.
3. No more Sandbox solutions support. In other words, sandbox solutions will be available for backwards compatibility with existing sandbox solutions. SharePoint 2013 introduced the New App model and the Old SharePoint Farm solutions.

A complete list of features deprecated can be found on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607742%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

**Edit**: Added a more clarified response for Sandbox solutions.

Comment: +1 Although interestingly that page on TechNet doesn't list the two I mentioned.

Comment: That's correct! But don't forget, we're still looking at the preview version and hopefully Microsoft will improve the documentation, or provide some guidance around missing features.

Comment: Sandbox solutions are actually still in place.

Comment: Just updated my reponse that sandbox solutions will be available for backwards compatibility...

Answer (score 4):

The sign in as another user function - which I use all the time.

Answer (score 3):

Not many am sure of but adding to above answers,

ULS log folder isn't there where it was used to be in previous versions of SharePoint

[where-did-my-owa-uls-logs-go-in-sharepoint-2013](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2012/10/12/where-did-my-owa-uls-logs-go-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of workflow actions that are deprecated, [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163929%28v=office.15%29.aspx), involving permissions among other things.

They are available using something called the "Workflow interop bridge".

Answer (score 3):

Installing SP2013 on Windows 7 or 8 for development purposes is not supported:

> We support installation of SharePoint 2013 only on Windows Server 2008
>   R2 Service Pack 1 x64 or Windows Server 2012. If you want to develop
>   apps for SharePoint for SharePoint 2013 on Windows 7 or Windows 8, you
>   can sign up for an Office 365 Developer Site and develop apps
>   remotely. See How to: Set up an environment for developing apps for
>   SharePoint on Office 365 for instructions about how to create this
>   sort of development environment

From [Start: Set up the development environment for SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx#SP15_bk_InstallOS)

Answer (score 1):

Tables in layout, if they count as a feature.

Comment: In what context? I'm a bit lost.

Comment: I'm saying <table> finally made way for <div> elements in html :)

Comment: Oh I see! :) I was thinking of web part pages templates...

Answer (score -2):

When ever Create New web application Hide Authentication by default it takes Classic Authentication. If we want Claims Go with Powershell enble Claims.

Comment: Wrong, by default it takes Claims, because that's the only one that works with OAuth and Apps. If you want Classic you have to use powershell