# Implementing permissions based on metadata

Tags: permissions, metadata

It's been 10 years Sharepoint is around, but this feature is still missing OOB. It would help immensely in governing a Sharepoint farm, IMHO. Administrators should only setup the rules as staten by the business, then nothing is to be done later.

We are doing in a limited way by using custom workflows with custom lists which maps the relation between security groups and managed metadata.

I am wondering, anyone has implemented this with some custom code ? I know there is a product called Titus, anyone has used it successfully in real world ?. Not sure how it would impact the Sharepoint installation,  I am always skeptical of installing third party solutions.

Answer (score 3):

I think an eventreceiver should handle this pretty well.  Here's some code that I haven't tested but looks pretty sound:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/18dcb996-5352-4856-b526-b69ccc71180e/

If you wanted more flexible solution, you could implement the event receiver to read from a property bag or some other configuration store and create an application page to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2010 you can assign permissions via SharePoint Designer workflows.  So, you could use the metadata in the workflow to assign permissions as necessary.

Comment: Note that the ability to do this is [deprecated in 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163929(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: "Add list item permissions" is the first one on the list in your link. Deprecated beyond 2013 perhaps, but still possible within 2013.

Comment: Something for http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/49622/627 ? :)