# Is there a way to limit viewing permissions of list items based on a property?

Tags: permissions, security, custom-list

I have a custom list which has a property "Department" which is a multi-select checkbox list. So each item in this list can be one of multiple different Departments. I would like to make these items only available to people in that given department. For example, if someone is in the "Accounting" group on the SBS, can I make the custom list so that user can see "Accounting" specific items and no others?

In the same sense, if someone is a part of multiple different departments, they should be able to see all items which fall under each department.

I'm using SharePoint 2010 integrated with SBS 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a similar question here: [Implementing permissions based on metadata](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49658/implementing-permissions-based-on-metadata)

Doing it involves custom workflows or event receivers. It also mentions [Titus Metadata Security](http://www.titus.com/software/sharepoint/metadata.php) available as a 3rd party solution.

Comment: I ended up implementing the idea I presented as an answer in that other post and it works pretty good.